# User permissions full from app but only select and view from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am creating a special user which I have to give full permissions in the app execution but only select and view when I use Workbrench or the console using MySQL.

Is it possible? It is for security reasons.

I asked this question because programmers can see the user in C# web.config and we are not interested they do direct queries of insert and updates in the console.

Comment: Given you use a program like phpmyadmin you can easily describe the possibilities of users. Open the tab useraccounts and edit the data-tab on the left (select, insert, update, delete and file) for the specific user.

Comment: Mysql is not aware what client program you use when you connect to mysql, so there is no way of restricting a user based on the client program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A given user can only have one set of privileges. It doesn't matter what program they use when they connect. You can't make the user have different privileges depending on the client program.

But you can grant different privileges depending on the client *host*.

A "user" in MySQL is the combination of the name and the client host from which it connects. Even if the username and password are identical, if the client connects from an app server host, it could match the `user@host` entry that has full privileges, and then if the client connects from any other host (e.g. a developer workstation or a jump host), grant only the limited privileges you want.

The way you would do this is to create two users. Suppose your app server hosts are all in the subnet `192.168.200.%`:

```
CREATE USER 'app'@'192.168.200.%' IDENTIFIED BY '...';

CREATE USER 'app'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '...';
```

Then grant privileges accordingly:

```
CREATE SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON appdb.* TO  'app'@'192.168.200.%';

GRANT SELECT ON appdb.* TO 'app'@'%';
```

When the MySQL authentication system recognizes a login, it matches it to the most specific host pattern first.

This assumes the developers don't have ssh access to the app server hosts. But even if they do, you could set up monitoring so you'd have a log if they ever do log into the app server hosts and run the mysql command-line client.